# Set length of a special regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem with some regular expression's length the deal is that this Regex :

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:[_ .][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

should only accept strings like :

```
[str][White space or . or _][str][White space or . or _][str]...[str]
```

[White space or . or _] : should not be repeated in the same sequence.

My question is **how can i limit the full string's length to between {6,12}**, i tried with :

```
^[[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:[_ .][A-Za-z0-9]+)*]{6,12}$
```

But it didn't work well it causes the repetition of [White space or . or _] beside it allows them to be at the edges of the string.

Best regards.

Comment: Why not simply test `input.size()`?

Comment: I know, but I am trying to master regular expressions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a lookahead for this:

```
^(?=.{6,12}$)[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:[_ .][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Makes sure the coming match is between 6 to 12 characters long.